# Remove subdivision surface?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Hello is possible to remove subdivision surface from object after applied ? In some history or something?
I applied a subdivision surface and saved the file.....

Thank you!

Comment: See if anything here works: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/recover.html

Answer (score 3):

Unless you haven't closed the file and you applied the modifier recently enough (in which case you may be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> back to it), there is no way to "un-apply" a modifier.

A tool that may work for you though is the *un-subdivide* tool.  Go into edit mode, selet the entire mesh, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for "unsubdivide".